# Relative 3D rotation change according to current rotation

Tags: java, matrix, opengl-es, rotation, geometry

I rotate an object in 3D space in XYZ by 90 degree steps, (rX rY rZ). The angle's are limited to 0-360 degree and I use the following commands for rotating the matrix:

```
Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, rX, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, rY, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, rZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

To figure out in what direction the up, right and away of the object ended up after the rotation I simply parse the 3x3 upper left of the rotation matrix. That works great by reading:

```
mRotationMatrix[0], mRotationMatrix[1], mRotationMatrix[2]
mRotationMatrix[4], mRotationMatrix[5], mRotationMatrix[6]
mRotationMatrix[8], mRotationMatrix[9], mRotationMatrix[10]
```

From here I need to figure out how I can update rX, rY, rZ using four different formulas|commands|functions where each rotates the object along the resulting X and Y axis back and forward. Imagine like if the four commands can push the object at four directions and the object will "roll" 90 degree in that direction.

I have no other information and can only manipulate the rX, rY and rZ rotation variables. I must not add a fourth rotation to the result. Somehow I must calculate what change to rX, rY and rZ respectively will have the same effect on the resulting rotation matrix independently of what the rX, rY and rZ already are set to.

I can't figure the maths out. Knowing what side of the object is currently pointing up isn't enough since it can be rotated in four different directions and still have the same side up, etc. Even if I know exactly in what directions the six sides of the object is pointing I still can't figure out what of the rX, rY or rZ I should manipulate to achieve the rotation.

I am starting to lean towards creating a hardcoded lookup-table for all possible combinations, but I really want to avoid that (I guess that would be 4*4*4*4, where the last four is the "roll" direction).

Another way of seeing it is instead of thinking of rolling the top side 90 degrees to any of the four sides facing left, right, away or near one can say that I need to figure out how I can manipulate rX, rY and rZ to rotate any of the sides of the object, except for up or down, to the top side. I hope that explains what my goal is.